# Make copy paste from columns to rows faster

Tags: excel, vba

I need copy paste from columns to rows. Something like truncate but copy fields it depends from column 6.

How can I make this faster?

```vb
Dim sh As Worksheet 
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")   
Dim counter As Long    
counter = sh.Range("B7", sh.Range("B7").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count    
Dim Row As Long    
     
For k = 0 To counter    
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
    For I = 0 To Cells(7 + k, 6).Value + 5    
        Cells((lastRow + 1) + I, 1).Value = Cells(7 + k, 2 + I).Value    
    Next I    
Next k
```

[image]

Comment: What does it do? Add more detail. Are `sh` and `ActiveSheet` the same worksheet? Maybe add some screenshots (e.g. for the before and the after). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72198867/edit) at any time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post a data example and the expected output?

Comment: Can you share the purpose? May be, you could use copy data to optimize it.

Comment: I added example. sh and activesheet its the same

Comment: Looking at your image, it looks like you just want to copy first row of data and transpose it. Please check [Transpose (rotate) data from rows to columns or vice versa](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744)

Comment: Yes I want transpose it, but in vba because I have more than 1000 rows.

Comment: Could you share **what** exactly you want to copy and **where to** e.g. columns of `A8:F21` to `H8:U13` (or just `H8` is enough, transpose is already understood)?

Comment: So, you want pasting the first 6 columns, per each row (B:G) from "Test" sheet to the active one, placing the transposed range in "A:A" column, one below the the previous range.  Would such an understanding be correct? Or you want pasting in the same sheet and you just mixed "Test" sheet with the active one?

Answer (score 1):

Please test the next code. It is based on what I could understand from the picture you show us, even if it may not be completed, in terms of columns to be transposed, copied. If you need to paste in another sheet, please try better describing what you really want accomplishing:

```
Sub testTransposeRowsSameSheet()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngTr As Range
 Dim lastR As Long, lastRow As Long, k As Long, arrRow
   
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngTr = sh.Range("B7", "G" & lastR) 'it may be sh.Range("B7", "O" & lastR) if you need all these columns


  ReDim arrRow(1 To 1, 1 To rngTr.Columns.count)
 For k = 1 To rngTr.rows.count
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 6 Then lastRow = 6
    arrRow = rngTr.rows(k).value
    sh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(UBound(arrRow, 2), 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrRow)
 Next k
End Sub
```

Since, you speak about the code being slow, you maybe try processing a much larger range. For such a case, the next function will be also fast for larger ranges. It load everything in an array (working in memory) and drop the result at the end, at once:

```
Sub testTransposeRowsSameSheetArray()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngTr As Range, arr, j As Long, kk As Long
 Dim lastR As Long, lastRow As Long, k As Long, arrRow
   
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngTr = sh.Range("B7", "K" & lastR) 'it may be sh.Range("B7", "O" & lastR) if you need all these columns

  ReDim arrRow(1 To 1, 1 To rngTr.Columns.count)
  ReDim arr(1 To rngTr.Columns.count * rngTr.rows.count, 1 To 1): kk = 1
  If UBound(arr) > 1048576 Then MsgBox "The necessary array exceeds the maximum sheet number of rows...": Exit Sub
 For k = 1 To rngTr.rows.count
    arrRow = rngTr.rows(k).value
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrRow, 2)
        arr(kk, 1) = arrRow(1, j): kk = kk + 1
    Next j
 Next k
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 If lastRow < 7 Then lastRow = 6
 sh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

If you want pasting the transposed rows from "Test" sheet to the active one, please try the next way:

```
Sub testTransposeRows_2Sheets()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, actSh As Worksheet, rngTr As Range
 Dim lastR As Long, lastRow As Long, k As Long, arrRow
   
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
  Set actSh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngTr = sh.Range("B7", "G" & lastR)

  ReDim arrRow(1 To 1, 1 To 6)
 For k = 1 To rngTr.rows.count
    lastRow = actSh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    arrRow = rngTr.rows(k).value
    actSh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(UBound(arrRow, 2), 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrRow)
 Next k
End Sub
```

But if you want transposing everything from the mentioned columns in "Test" sheet in the active one, starting from "A7", try the next way:

```
Sub testTransposeAll()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, actSh As Worksheet, arrTr, lastR As Long
   
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
  Set actSh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  arrTr = sh.Range("B7", "G" & lastR).value
  actSh.Range("A7").Resize(UBound(arrTr, 2), UBound(arrTr)).value = Application.Transpose(arrTr)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's good, but when I have date in column E (custom), then it's trancated not as the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Cleot123 I do  not understand anything. What do you mean by "date in column E (custom)"? All above versions works on **rows**, starting from column B:B. What do you mean by **it's trancated not as the same"? Please, clearly explain what you try doing and what does not work as you want. An example will probably help...